# Google's MDL - Dialog not closing in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dialog, modal-dialog

I am using Google's Material Design.

I have put a dialog in but it doesn't seem to close in Safari. (It does close in Chrome).

Dialog:

```
<dialog class="mdl-dialog">
        <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Question Help</h4>
        <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
            <p>
                Help text will go here dynamically.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" id="closeModal" class="mdl-button close">Close</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>
```

Javascript rendering the Dialog:

```
  let dialog            = document.querySelector('dialog');
  let showDialogButton  = document.querySelectorAll('.show-dialog');
  let i;

  if (! dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }

 for (i = 0; i < showDialogButton.length; ++i) {
   showDialogButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
     dialog.showModal();
   });
}

  dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  dialog.close();
```

});

I have console.log(); inside the event listener and it isn't  getting inside the function. But it is picking up the  .close element. So I don't think the event listener is firing?

Any ideas why the dialog doesn't close?

Answer (score 0):

Move the dialog under the `<body>`

From the [dialog polyfill docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill):

> Modal dialogs have limitations-
>
> They should be a child of `<body>` or have parents without layout (aka,
>   no position absolute or relative elements)